# Mysql - Information schema - How to query multiple Woocommerce tables on Wordpress Multisite?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am trying to get from the WordPress database all orders of each site of the multisite.

I use MySQL workbench and I am trying to achieve it with the following code, is anyone available to explain what I am missing?

This seems not working:

```
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE '%posts'  and post_type="shop_order";
```

Comment: The information schema maintains data about your tables, but it does not contain your actual data. For that, you will need to query the appropriate databases.

Comment: thanks for that Jeremy! after removing 'and post_type...' I see all the tables I need (wp_posts, wp_1_posts, wp_2_posts) under the column TABLES_NAME but still can't figure out how to query them all now and get the list of orders.